# How to programmatically add site to "Local Intranet" zone?

Tags: internet-explorer

I've found out how to do it for Trusted Sites, but can't find for the Local Intranet. I'm talking about IE Security zones from Internet Options.

Comment: Sorry - voted to close before I saw "programmatically". My bad, would retract my close vote if I could.

Comment: @Dominic: Just click on the "Down" arrow again.

Comment: @Aaron - I didn't downvote, I voted to close.

Comment: I would consider this a security risk, if sites can somehow be included to a more trusted zone without user interference. Basically, you're telling the browser that the site is part of the local Intranet. Then again, I wonder if this is even possible... You need to be inside the firewalled area to have your site included in this zone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turned out that it is exactly the same as adding to 'Trusted Sites' ([stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972345/programmatically-add-trusted-sites-to-internet-explorer)) but with setting the registry value to 1, not 2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link that contains a C# project that appears to be able to do this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/01/26/361228.aspx

Here's a link to the project's source code:

http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/content/SetZoneMappingDemo.zip