# How to add URL to the trusted zone in Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, trusted-sites

How can I add an URL to the trusted site? It seems that there are stored in the registry, but where exactly?
The hints I've googled so far weren't helpfull.

The .net programm will run locally on each client.

**Edit clarification**: I want to do this programmaticly running C# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should give you the way to do it in code...

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/01/26/361228.aspx

**-- EDIT --**

The original URL has expired, so here's a copy from the archives:

https://web.archive.org/web/20051028021129/http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2005/01/26/361228.aspx

The sample project .ZIP file is downloadable there as well.

Comment: The code you posted wraps a Com object. Might there be another solution involving the registry?

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569)

[Adding Sites Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537181%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/ddietric/archive/2009/06/24/adding-and-removing-websites-from-security-zones-programmatically-c.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972345/programmatically-add-trusted-sites-to-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

Check this [solution](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=368335) at CodeGuru forums.

In summary, this code uses the COM library, a library which you did say you wished to avoid. However, there is no workaround this situation. Another thing to mention is that this code is written in C++, as the guy who wrote it, [CorithMartin](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/member.php?u=193100), ported it from C#.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "urlmon.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#include <atldef.h>
#include <atlconv.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // constants from urlmon.h
    const int URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0;
    const int URLZONE_INTRANET = URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE + 1;
    const int URLZONE_TRUSTED = URLZONE_INTRANET + 1;
    const int URLZONE_INTERNET = URLZONE_TRUSTED + 1;
    const int URLZONE_UNTRUSTED = URLZONE_INTERNET + 1;
    const int URLZONE_ESC_FLAG = 0x100;
    const int SZM_CREATE  = 0;
    const int SZM_DELETE  = 0x1;

    HRESULT hr;
    IInternetSecurityManager *pSecurityMgr;
    LPCWSTR sites = SysAllocString(L"http://*.mydomain.com");

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetSecurityManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IInternetSecurityManager, (void**)&pSecurityMgr);

    pSecurityMgr->SetZoneMapping(URLZONE_TRUSTED, sites, SZM_CREATE);

    pSecurityMgr->Release();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It lies indeed in the registry, and it's described right there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537181%28VS.85%29.aspx

Beware of the UAC in Vista though. It's a real pain to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell

```
#Setting IExplorer settings
Write-Verbose "Now configuring IE"
#Add http://website.com as a trusted Site/Domain
#Navigate to the domains folder in the registry
set-location "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set-location ZoneMap\Domains

#Create a new folder with the website name
new-item website/ -Force
set-location website/
new-itemproperty . -Name * -Value 2 -Type DWORD -Force
new-itemproperty . -Name http -Value 2 -Type DWORD -Force
new-itemproperty . -Name https -Value 2 -Type DWORD -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a new trusted zone it creates zone registry keys and folders on the path
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains
for each domain it creates a new 
key with domain name ( sample.com)
a new key under this one with the subdomain (www)
and under this one a new REG_DWORD with name of the scheme (http or https)
value 2 on hexadecimal and that is it,you got it done

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to simplify the process.

1. Create a .exe to ask for the domain (a textbox), specify the
   providers (as checkboxes: All, http, https, ftp) click "Add Site to
   Trusted Sites" to then do the following:
2. Create a temp folder on C: as "C:\TempTS\"
3. Create a .bat file ("C:\TempTS\AddTrustedSites.bat") similar to this:

> set regFile="C:\TempTS\AddTrustedSiteTS.reg"
>
> ECHO Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > %regFile%
>
> ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\MySecureDomain.com\www] >> %regFile
>
> ECHO "https"=dword:00000002 >> %regFile%
>
> regedit /s %regFile%
>
> DEL %regFile%

The **ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER...** and **ECHO "https"...** lines can be repeated for each provider checked.  For the "ALL" provider, use an asterisk in place of "https", like such:

> ECHO [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\MySecureDomain.com\www] >> %regFile%
>   ECHO "*"=dword:00000002 >> %regFile%

Run the .bat file using this call:

> **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\TempTS\AddTrustedSites.bat")**

After the .bat file is ran (takes mere microseconds), delete both the bat file and tempTS directory.

MacSpudster

(a.k.a. GNoter, TechStuffBC)

=========================

*Credit where credit is due:*

> **regedit /s AddTrustedSite.reg**
>
> the "/s" will supress confirm dialog boxes
>
> http://www.computerhope.com/registry.html

also:

> see http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/bat-file-to-add-trusted-site-in-ie/139995.html