# Download file is blocked using WatiN even after modifying registry settings

Tags: download, watin, access-control

I'm doing an IE automation using WatiN.

When a file to be downloaded is clicked, I get the following in the Internet Explorer Information bar:

> To help protect your security,
>   Internet Explorer has blocked this
>   site from downloading files to you
>   computer.

I added a registry key to,

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\

then a REG_DWORD value named "http" with value==2 as given in [Programmatically add trusted sites to Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972345/programmatically-add-trusted-sites-to-internet-explorer)

but still facing same issues. Can some1 advice on this....

Answer (score 3):

1. In Internet Explorer, click Tools.
2. Click Internet Options.
3. Under the Security tab, click Custom Level.
4. Scroll to the Downloads section. Then set Automatic prompting for file downloads to Enable.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your security 'zone' to trusted sites, adding the site you're downloading from to your trusted sites, and setting the security level to low.  seems to work for me