# Downloading file and internet security issue

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, watin

I have an application that downloads a file from a website,
I'm using watin and c# to download the file.

Environment : Windows server 8 64bit

The problem is when i run the application i get the warning:
"To help protect your security, Windows Internet Explorer blocked this site from downloading files to your computer"

But if i navigate to the website and click manually download, then no issue.

I'm not able to change the settings of internet explorer

How can i avoid this warning in c# and watin?

Comment: Maybe you could try this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c

Comment: I cannot do that because i don't know the name of the file in advance 
plus i must perform some clickes and checkboxes via watin then click on an image to download.

Comment: Have you tried changing your IE trusted site settings ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675055/download-file-is-blocked-using-watin-even-after-modifying-registry-settings

Comment: I don't have the rights to do that! i only can add websites to trust zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's impossible to do that :-( 
The only solution provided by a professional is to adjust manually the security settings of IE