# Add to Trusted Site

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, settings, regedit, trusted-sites

What we did:

We have created an activex which installs through the web browser into client machine

What are the Problems facing now?

We are trying to add the site in trusted site list

Which we wrote the code in Activex. So while installing it adds the site to Trusted sites list

But it is not affected immediately

Answer (score 1):

Some code would be nice or more details. Here is a list of resources though:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537181(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649488(v=vs.85).aspx

[Programmatically add trusted sites to Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972345/programmatically-add-trusted-sites-to-internet-explorer)

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=368335

Hope this helps.